# Processing animation while running batch class from apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

I have a batch class and i want to create a visual force tab. when user will click on the tab , batch class will get executed and it will show gif animation while batch class will process. Animation will get stop when batch execution will be completed.

Vf page :

```
    <apex:page controller="FT_VfPageForSyncPricbookBatchController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pg">
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!batchStatusBool}">
             <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" style="align:center;" startText="Processing..." >
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                  <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.LoadingImage}" style="align:center;" width="200" height="200"/>                   
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
           <apex:actionPoller interval="5" action="{!checkBatchStatus}" enabled="{!pollerBool}" reRender="pg" status="actStatusId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller class:

```
ublic with sharing class FT_VfPageForSyncPricbookBatchController {
public Boolean batchStatusBool {get;set;}
public String batchStatus {get;set;}
public Id batchId;
public Boolean pollerBool {get;set;}

public FT_VfPageForSyncPricbookBatchController(){
    batchStatusBool = true;
    FCC_SyncPriceBookEntry obj = new FCC_SyncPriceBookEntry(); // batch class
    batchId= Database.executeBatch(obj,2); // id is not getting stored in batchId according to me
    system.debug('Haha@@@@@'+batchId);
    checkBatchStatus();
}

 public void checkBatchStatus() {
    List<AsyncApexJob> job = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =:batchId];
    batchStatus = job[0].Status;
    system.debug('======='+batchStatus);
    if(batchStatus == 'Completed') {
        pollerBool = false;
    } else {
        pollerBool = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code with us. Is it working? If it is not working, please **[edit]** your code to explicitly state what is wrong, sharing any error messages verbatim.